# Does Google Index links created with onclick='window.location'

Tags: seo

I have many links in my site such as:

Are they indexed as regular  hyperlinks or not?

Comment: Probably not, and why would you do such a thing in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. Search engines generally don't process JavaScript but they are starting to handle basic JavaScript of which `onclick='window.location'` falls under. So they might but they're probably not as valuable as normal link would be if they are. (Internal links do have SEO value).

Answer (score -1):

For Google yes !
His crawler handle simple javascrpit redirection including onclick='window.location'.
He doesn't gave as weight as a classic href link but he can index your page with it !